# Ratio of outer circle to inner circle diameter in pentagon star

Tags: geometry

I am trying to write a code to draw pentagon star and have stumbled upon a problem. In the attached diagram, what is the ratio of the diameter of outer (red) circle to the inner (blue) circle. The circles are concentric. I've [read](http://www.hypermaths.org/cropcircles/chapter5/) that it is ~2.61 but would like to develop the relationship myself.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Math Behind Creating a “Perfect” Star](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135982/math-behind-creating-a-perfect-star/2136327).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Robert Israel :  Here is an alternate proof, involving only triangle trigonometry.

With notations displayed on the figure below, we have to find the ratio $\dfrac{OA}{OB}.$

- by reasoning in right triangle $OCA \ $: $ \ \widehat{OAB}=90°-72°=18°.$
- by reasoning in right triangle $OCB \ $: $ \ \widehat{OBC}=90°-72°/2=54°$, thus $\widehat{ABO}=180°-54°=126°.$

Thus, sine law in triangle $OAB$ gives:

$$\tag{1}\dfrac{OA}{OB}=\dfrac{\sin \widehat{ABO}}{\sin \widehat{OAB}}=\dfrac{\sin 126°}{\sin 18°}=\dfrac{\cos 36°}{\cos 72°}$$
 (exact value); thus $\dfrac{OA}{OB}\approx 2.618.$

Knowing that $\cos 36°=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$, it is not difficult to conclude that the exact value can also be written$1+\Phi$ (where $\Phi:=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio).
[image]

Comment: Knowing cos 36 and sin 18 *seems* esoteric, but you can calculate, say, sin 18 by using the identity cos 3x = sin 2x. cos 3x = 4cos^3 x - 3 cos x can be derived from seeing cos 3x + cos x = cos (2x+x) + cos (2x-x). Or you can use geometry to derive things: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenTriangle.html has more information.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: everything can be done with analytic geometry.
If the outer radius is $R$, then in a cartesian coordinate system the vertices on the outer circle are at $[0,R], \ldots$.  Find the
equations of the lines, see where they intersect...